# Google sheet drop down and calculations

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I'm trying to figure out how to dynamically have multiple drop-down values calculated as per what's in the cells in Google Sheets. Not sure if I'm using the correct text or how to describe what I'm looking for.

I'm working for a building company I want to find out how to calculate which house will fit on a certain sized amount of land, based off the R code that the suburb has and the frontage of the property.

#### Example data:

```
Size of a block is from 80m2 and up to 5000m2
R-Codes are: 2,2.5,5,10,12.5,15,17.5,20,25,30,35,40,50,60,80
Frontage (m) can be: 7.5,8.5,10,12,12.5,14,15,15.65,17
```

R Codes determine the size of the house that can be built on the land provided.

#### Example:

```
R Code:         Min size house:
2,2.5           20% of land size
5               30% of land size
10              40% of land size
12.5            45% of land size
15,17.5,20,25   50% of land size
30,35,40        55% of land size
50,60           60% of land size
80              70% of land size
```

So if a client has a 350m2 piece of land and the code for that area is R20 then the size of the house that can be built on that land is 175m2.

I want the drop down to have the option for each field

Block size | R Code | Frontage | and calculate the size of the house size

With this information, we could reference a house a model that can fit on the block and be shown to a client.

#### Example:

```
Name            House size (m2)  Frontage (m)
Davenport       176.8            8.5
```

I'm playing around with these formulas:

```
=if(B2<5,(A2/100)*20,"")
```

This tells me if r codes are under 5 (R codes:2,2.5) multiply the block by a percentage (relating to that R code)

Trying to figure out which formulae can be introduced into the calculation and produce the correct answer with all the conditions.

I don't have any coding experience

Comment: pls explain how Frontage fits in calculation

Comment: Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/5632629/player0

Comment: Frontage means the front of the home. Each block has a different frontage to it depending what's been done with the land. Also, R codes from 2 to 25 specify a minimum frontage. For example, if the 350m2 block has 8m frontage I would tell which house design would fit.

Comment: I get it but still no idea how its affecting 175m2. or should it? if you could explain it in more detail I could translate it into a formula

Comment: Now that you've created the formulae I can see what you mean. Let me get back to you. I'll ask a manager.

Comment: Ok I just asked someone why the frontage is so important. Its because a narrow home is more expensive to build than a squarer home with the same area.

Comment: Ok, I just asked someone why the frontage is so important. Its because a narrow home is more expensive to build than a squarer home with the same area. For example, if two clients wanted to build a 200m2 home one of them had a narrower block and the frontage was 10m and the other had a 12.5m. They both want to build a 200m2 home but the person with the 10m frontage has a 60m perimeter while the other person has a 57m2. Same size house but the price could be $5000min difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2, 
 {{2,    20%};
  {2.5,  20%};
  {5,    30%};
  {10,   40%};
  {12.5, 45%};
  {15,   50%};
  {17.5, 50%};
  {20,   50%};
  {25,   50%};
  {30,   55%};
  {35,   55%};
  {40,   55%};
  {50,   60%};
  {60,   60%};
  {80,   70%}}, 2, 0)*A2, )
```

[image: 0]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tuhi0QjlvUw3ysMXlHqNPjOOAcVbgUu0jYm4aZ9lK2s/copy)

Comment: Thank you, I had a formula work and was using this: =if(B2<5,(A2/100)*20,IF(B2=5,(A2/100)*30,IF(B2=10,(A2/100)*40,IF(B2=12.5,(A2/100)*45,IF(B2=15,(A2/100)*50,IF(B2=17.5,(A2/100)*50,IF(B2=20,(A2/100)*50,IF(B2=25,(A2/100)*50,IF(B2=30,(A2/100)*55,IF(B2=35,(A2/100)*55,IF(B2=40,(A2/100)*55,IF(B2=50,(A2/100)*60,IF(B2=60,(A2/100)*60,IF(B2=80,(A2/100)*70,""))))))))))))))

Comment: Yours is better as it doesn't show anything if the cells are blank. Thank you